# Was Chernobyl Explosion a Small Nuclear Detonation?

Tags: thermodynamics, nuclear-physics, radioactivity, nuclear-engineering, explosions

The Chernobyl reactor was designed to produce a maximum of 3.2 megawatts of power.  It is now estimated to have produced 3.2 gigawatts of power in the final second of its life.

The original hypothesis is that the the explosions at [Chernobyl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_disaster) were either steam/steam or steam/hydrogen explosions.

A new hypothesis is that the first explosion was actually a small nuclear detonation of the runaway fissioning.  The total energy released in the first blast was 320 gigawatt thermal.

This new hypothesis is based on observations from witnesses who were nearby and saw the explosions.  The first explosion turned the air blue from fluorescence of excited oxygen and nitrogen atoms in the air.

Is there a way to determine how powerful the explosion was?   Also is it possible this was a quasi atomic explosion due to runaway fissioning?

The paper I am reading is linked below.

https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00295450.2017.1384269

Comment: *The Chernobyl reactor was designed to produce a maximum of 3.2 megawatts of power.* This seems much too low.

Comment: *The total energy released in the first blast was 320 gigawatt thermal.* Energy is not measured in watts.

Comment: @G.Smith - you are right.  I apologize.  It was designed to produce 3200 MWth and 1000 MWe

Comment: @Rick So you say the reactor has been designed to operate 3.2 hours. The units are MW ( megawatt, power ) and MWh ( megawatthour, energy, the power of 1 MW in duration of 1 hour )

Comment: @Poutnik - Where do you see in the above that I said it was designed to run for 3.2 hours?  My mistake was under reporting the power output of the reactor not in its units of measure.  According to estimates it was designed to run at 3200 megwatt therm...not 3.2.  

Please stop trying to nitpick everything I write and help me understand what the difference is between a runaway and uncontrolled fission process in a reactor and a small atomic detonation.... both are self sustaining chain reactions leading to an explosion.

Comment: Forgot for now nuclear energy and focus on what is detonation and what is not. If you were overheating the pressured casserole fo 15 minutes and it exploded, does that mean water detonated ?

Comment: These types of things are a conspiracy in nature and involve national sabotage. Any physical explanation by people who do not acknowledge this basic fact will be misleading

Comment: @ChemEng - who said anything about conspiracy theories?  My question was, at the megawattage Chernobyl achieved before it exploded, was it close to a small nuclear detonation.  It was not...

Comment: [MIT 22.01](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ijst4g5KFN0).

Comment: The Chernobyl reactor was not designed to produce a maximum of 3.2 MW of power. Energy is not measured in GW.

Answer (score 6):

Nuclear reactors have too low uranium enrichment to be capable of nuclear explosion, not even a [detonation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detonation?wprov=sfla1)(explosion with supersonic velocity of propagation).

But the thermal power of uncontrolled fission may lead to mechanical explosion by pressurised gas or water vapour, or there can occur secondary chemical explosion by ignition of developed and escaped hydrogen.

[RBMK-1000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RBMK?wprov=sfla1) reactor, used in Chernobyl, had nominal power 1000 MW. There were/are in use also RBMK-1500 and some designs were projected up to 2400 MW.

Explosion can be defined as very fast energy release, with extremely high power and very short time duration, with sharp begin and end.

Detonation is explosion propagating in exploding material by speed exceeding speed of sound in material. Additionally, explosion is not matter of total released energy but matter of way how it is released.

Nuclear detonation of fissionable material requires for this material to sustain runaway chain reaction of **fast** (x MeV ) neutrons.

2-3% 235U, additionally with fission products absorbing neutrons, scattered in small pieces across the big volume, cannot nuclearly detonate.

If it could, the detonation would not be small, but huge, temperature would reach some 100 millions K instead of few thousands and all power plant and close neighborhood would evaporate.

TNT explosive energy ( about 10% of coal energy ) is approx 4.2 MJ / kg. 3.2 GW of thermal power is equivalent cca 760 kg TNT/s. Equivalent of 75 ton TNT is released during less than 2 minutes of **nominal** reactor function.

Overheating of pressured casserole, just little bigger and dramatic for lifes of too many people.

That means, if the power of energy being released is just in range of few multiples of nominal power, being increased gradually and continually, it can hardly be consider as a nuclear explosion.

OTOH, the sudden reactor break can be, but as a mechanical explosion, even if based on originally nuclear energy.

Comment: At what point is a runaway fission process = small atomic detonation.  I believe the estimate was 75 tons of TNT for the main blast.....  Could steam alone account for such an energetic explosion.  Please remember that the reactor had only about a 1/3 the water in it that it was supposed to have due to the pumps shutting down and a lot had already flashed to steam....

Comment: Detonation is explosion propagating in exploding material by speed exceeding speed of sound in material. Additionally, explosion is not matter of total released energy but matter of way how it is released. If there exploded equivalent to 75 kt TNT, there would be no reactor to cover and spreading of radioactivity would my much worse.

Comment: Not 75 kT - just 75 tons.

Comment: Nuclear explosion equivalent to 75 ton TNT is not possible even for pure 235U, not speaking of enriched uranium with just max 3% of fissibke 235U.

Comment: Actually it is... The W54 was one of the smallest nuclear warheads deployed by the United States. It was a very compact 2-point implosion-type nuclear weapon design, designed for tactical use and had a very low yield for a nuclear weapon, in the range of 10 to 1,000 tons TNT equivalent.

My question still remains... Where is the dividing line between a runaway fission process and an atomic detonation.  Even an imprecise very low yield detonation....

Comment: But W54 did not use 235U. It's critical mas is 52 kg, in the most efficient spherical shape. W54 mass of the while package was less than half of that. Difference ? Huge. 2-3% 235U, additionally with fission products absorbing neutrons, scattered in small pieces across the big volume, cannot nuclearly detonate. Full stop. If it could, the detonation would not be small, but huge, all power plant and close neighborhood would evaporate.

Comment: Again you missed the point of my comment in your attempt to simply prove me wrong.  My whole question in this is simple...  Where is the dividing line between a sustain but uncontrolled fission process leading to an explosion and a very small atomic bomb?  If as the paper suggests that the uncontrolled fission process lead to a 75 ton - TNT equivalent explosion before the fuel became plasma and stopped fissioning...  would this be a weird atomic explosion?     (Yes I know all about super criticality and how an atomic bomb works.  I was trained to destroy them in the military.)...

Comment: Learn what detonation is. Fitting the definition is the dividing line. Hint; it is not about the amount of released energy nor sustained power. Is Sun detonating ? Of course not.

Comment: 75 ton TNT is like 7.5 ton of coal.

Comment: TNT explosive energy ( about 10% of coal energy ) is approx 4.2 MJ / kg. 3.2 GW of thermal power is equivalent cca 760 kg TNT/s. 75 tón TNT Is released during less than 2 minutes of nominal reactor function. Overheating of pressured casserole, just little bigger.

Comment: @Rick The dividing line is whether the reaction rate is linear or exponential.

Comment: @PM 2Ring Not necessarily. If the exponential factor is small enough, and the rate is stopped soon enough, it  need not to lead even to explosion, not speaking to detonation. The runaway reactor fission does have an exponential part. But it's exponential growth is many orders slower. OTOH, pressure in pressured casserole increases exponentially with time, but it does not lead to detonation.

Comment: @Poutnik : To have an _efficient_ warhead, yes, you need all that stuff. But if your aim is simply to make an inefficient "fizzle", you can cause that with a much worse arrangement. The Chernobyl reactor had many tonnes - 1000s of kg - of total material, so it'd only take a tiny percentage "fizzling" in the same manner as a super-crude bomb, to get enough yield to blast the power plant wide open. I want to point out that inefficient "fizzle" purpose-made bombs have been speculated as a possible avenue for nuclear terrorism, so that it could happen accidentally is not out of the question.

Comment: Only takes about 3-4 grams of material to insta-fission to produce a 75 tonnes TNT equivalent nuclear explosion.

Comment: You need not nuclear detonation for that, similarly you need not high explosive for pressured casserole to explode.

Comment: Try it with power plant stuff. You will realize you need something else. 10 g of TNT can detonate, if hold together. But it would not detonate, if scattered over let say 1000 m3., would it ? 10000 tons of real TNT would not detonate, if 1 kg is spreaded in 1 m3. But it may decompose anyway, releasing the same energy in non detonating way.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer People inventing such speculative hypothesis focus rather on the topic popularity aspects than on mechanisms that could lead to what they describe.

Comment: @Poutnik : A nuclear "fizzle" is not speculation. It has happened in some attempts at bomb tests. There is a whole continuum of possible intensities of energy release from a nuclear reaction from a "simple" massive surfeit of radiation (e.g. the famous "Demon Core" incident that killed Louis Slotin in the Manhattan Project) all the way up to a "proper" weapons-level nuclear detonation.

Comment: ..bomb tests... Focus on mechanisms. Fission based on thermal neutrons cannot lead to fission detonation. Plant material cannot sustain runaway fission via fast neutrons. Other options ?

Comment: @Poutnik : Sure, but the paper also discusses the mechanism, and I do not see any good arguments here as to why it can't go. "That the explosion would be huge and wipe everything out" is not an argument if we consider only a very small percentage of material (here a few grams out of megagrams [tonnes] of total fuel, that's on the order of 0.001% or less) undergoing fission. As you said the ramp rate and other factors matter - if it ramps fast enough to get that <0.001% to release in a fraction of a second but not fast enough for more to do so before that release blows the rest apart...

Comment: If a casserole is collecting energy for long minutes, it need not to release it in fraction of a second. 75 tons TNT in less than 2 mins of nominal reactor ooeration, few dozens of seconds if out if hands. There is no detonation mechanism. Fast neutrons needed for detonation cannot detonate plant fuel. Slow neutrons cannot propagate fission rate increase enough and fast enough.  Have you ever heard about classical detonation lasting let's say 10 minutes ? If you have e.g a 10 km long high explosive filled rope (I forgot EN name for it ), its detonation lasts approx  1 s.

Answer (score 1):

A nuclear reactor cannot explode like a nuclear weapon. For a thermal reactor -like Chernobyl- the neutron generation lifetime is too long. For a fast reactor (and a thermal reactor) there is no mechanism for creating and maintaining a super prompt critical assembly sufficiently long for significant release of energy from fission. You have to really work hard to assemble the correct material to create a nuclear weapon; you need to create a system that is super prompt critical using fast neutrons and remains so sufficiently long for the chain reaction to produce enough energy before pressure causes dis-assembly into a non-critical configuration.  By super prompt critical is meant super critical on the prompt neutrons alone without having to wait for the delayed neutrons to contribute.  See the Los Alamos Primer by Serber, available from Amazon: the early notes on the physics of a fission weapon from Los Alamos at the beginning of the Manhattan project.

The explosions at Chernobyl were a steam explosion, and a chemical explosion caused by oxygen reacting with aerosolized graphite.  (At Three Mile Island the explosion was from oxygen reacting with hydrogen released from oxidation of the over-heated zircalloy fuel cladding.)

For a nuclear reactor, the safety concern is the removal of decay heat from the radioactive decay of fission products after the fission process is terminated.  Decay heat is about 5% of full power at shutdown.

A major problem with the Chernobyl design is the core was over-moderated.  Specifically, the graphite was the moderator and the cooling water was not needed as a moderator and in fact acted as a neutron poison.   So when the cooling water was lost the reactor power increased: positive feedback.  The old N reactor in the US was a graphite moderated, water cooled reactor used to produce Pu for the weapons program, but was specifically designed to not have this problem.

Also, Chernobyl did not have a robust reactor containment system, it had a reactor confinement system.

As an aside, there is a difference between deflagration and detonation; the former involves subsonic propagation of energy and the latter shock wave propagation of energy.  The name explosion in general use can refer to either.

Answer (score 0):

Nuclear explosions are characterized by prompt criticality.

> In nuclear engineering, prompt criticality describes a nuclear fission event in which criticality (the threshold for an exponentially growing nuclear fission chain reaction) is achieved with prompt neutrons alone (neutrons that are released immediately in a fission reaction) and does not rely on delayed neutrons (neutrons released in the subsequent decay of fission fragments). As a result, prompt supercriticality causes a much more rapid growth in the rate of energy release than other forms of criticality. Nuclear weapons are based on prompt criticality, while most nuclear reactors rely on delayed neutrons to achieve criticality.

Accidental nuclear explosions are not a new thing.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL-1

> On January 3, 1961, SL-1 was being prepared for restart after a shutdown of eleven days over the holidays. Maintenance procedures required that Rod 9 be manually withdrawn a few inches to reconnect it to its drive mechanism. At 9:01 pm, this rod was suddenly withdrawn too far, causing SL-1 to go prompt critical instantly. In four milliseconds, the heat generated by the resulting enormous power excursion caused fuel inside the core to melt and to explosively vaporize.

The paper you linked states:

> This paper renders the following hypothesis. The first explosion consisted of thermal neutron mediated nuclear explosions in one or rather a few fuel channels, which caused a jet of debris that reached an altitude of some 2500 to 3000 m. The second explosion would then have been the steam explosion most experts believe was the first one.

## The first explosion

The idea that Chernobyl involved a prompt criticality at some point was known long before that paper was published. For example, AS Dyatlov, Chernobyl engineer and witness, wrote in his 1991 memoir Chernobyl: How It Was (chapter 1)

> At 01:23:47 the reactor was destroyed with an acceleration of power on prompt neutrons. This collapse was the worst possible catastrophe in an energy reactor. No one could comprehend it, no one was prepared for it, no technical measures for localization of the unit and station had been stipulated. Nor were there any organizational measures.

[In a magazine article](https://www.neimagazine.com/features/featurehow-it-was-an-operator-s-perspective/) published that year, he makes it clear that this was the first explosion, consistent with your paper.

> The main circulating pumps kept up a flow of coolant right up to 01:23:46, when due to a sharp power rise the flow rate through the running down main circulating pumps (loop 1) and then that through the other pumps dropped. The pressure in loop 1 went up. At 01:23:46 or 01:23:47 a large explosion was heard and, one or two seconds later, there was another one, which in my perception was even bigger. And then the silence fell.

IAEA INSAG-7 page 69

> Owing to the design characteristics of the reactor, substantial damage to a few fuel assemblies (three or four fuel assemblies are enough) can, and in this case did, lead to the destruction of the reactor itself and the failure of it's emergency protection system. The rupture if the pipes of several fuel channels lead to an increase in pressure in the reactor space and partial detachment of the reactor support plate from the shroud and consequent jamming of the RCPS rods which by that time were only half way down.

Note: The "reactor space" mentioned above refers to the unpressurized space surrounding the fuel channels

That the above was indeed caused by prompt criticality is suggested by analysis results published in the report.

[image]

[Testimony](https://chernobylcritical.blogspot.com/p/part-5-after-explosion.html) of reactor operator LF Toptunov

> At the moment of the blast (or immediately afterwards) the control rods stopped moving...

From the above, a picture of the first, less dramatic explosion emerges of a localized prompt criticality causing a violent steam leak.

That the prompt criticality and steam leak were both part of the first explosion, rather than two separate explosions, is evidenced by eyewitness accounts and seismic data presented in your paper, both of which suggested a double blast as the first explosion.

## The second explosion

This was the more destructive explosion. Ruling out steam, we have two possible mechanisms for the explosion: hydrogen and nuclear.

The core at this point still existed, but the water had already leaked away through the gap between the side walls and the dislodged reactor lid. The very large void effect of reactivity could them allow a second much larger prompt criticality event.

This is supported by the graph below, also taken from the IAEA report.

[image]

The threshold for prompt criticality is usually 0.7%, though April 26 1986 at Chernobyl 4 was 0.5%

## Conclusion

The first explosion was probably a nuclear blast followed by a steam blast. The second explosion may have been a nuclear blast

Answer (score 0):

No, it was an energy induced thermochemical explosion. The reactor ruptured first creating a mimic of an explosion. Then water and superheated hydrogen differed from superheated water detonated.